# How to convert a struct column into rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have data as shown below:

```
    "Product": "ABC",
    "Value": {
        "Jan 2021": 10,
        "May 2021": 20,
        "Aug 2021": 30,
        "Jun 2021": 40,
        "Oct 2021": 50,
        "Sep 2021": 60,
        "Mar 2021": 70,
        "Feb 2021": 80,
        "Jul 2021": 90,
        "Apr 2021": 100,
        "Dec 2021": 110,
        "Nov 2021": 120
    }
```

```
 |-- Product: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Apr 2022: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Aug 2022: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Dec 2022: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Feb 2022: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Jan 2022: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Jul 2022: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Jun 2022: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Mar 2022: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- May 2022: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Nov 2022: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Oct 2022: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Sep 2022: double (nullable = true)
```

I want the output to be

| Product | Month | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Jan 2021 | 10 |
| ABC | Feb 2021 | 20 |
| ABC | Mar 2021 | 30 |
| ABC | Apr 2021 | 40 |
| ABC | May 2021 | 50 |
| ABC | Jun 2021 | 60 |

Tried using explode and *
But these give me data as columns but i want them as rows

Please assist

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stack](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#stack) function,

```
df= # input
struct_cols = df.select("Value.*").columns
stack_expr = ''.join([f"'{c}', `{c}` ," for c in struct_cols])[:-1]

df.select("Product", "Value.*").\
    selectExpr("Product", f"stack({len(struct_cols)}, {stack_expr} ) as (Month,Value)")\
    .show(truncate=False)

+-------+--------+-----+
|Product|Month   |Value|
+-------+--------+-----+
|ABC    |Apr 2021|100  |
|ABC    |Aug 2021|30   |
|ABC    |Dec 2021|110  |
|ABC    |Feb 2021|80   |
|ABC    |Jan 2021|10   |
|ABC    |Jul 2021|90   |
|ABC    |Jun 2021|40   |
|ABC    |Mar 2021|70   |
|ABC    |May 2021|20   |
|ABC    |Nov 2021|120  |
|ABC    |Oct 2021|50   |
|ABC    |Sep 2021|60   |
+-------+--------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a map and change it to columns,

```
cols = df.select('Value.*').columns
df.withColumn('Map', f.explode(f.array(*[f.create_map(f.lit('Month'), f.lit(col), f.lit('Value'), f.col('Value.' + col)) for col in cols]))) \
  .withColumn('Month', f.col('Map.Month')) \
  .withColumn('Value', f.col('Map.Value')) \
  .drop('Map') \
  .show(truncate=False)

+-------+-----+--------+
|Product|Value|Month   |
+-------+-----+--------+
|ABC    |100  |Apr 2021|
|ABC    |30   |Aug 2021|
|ABC    |110  |Dec 2021|
|ABC    |80   |Feb 2021|
|ABC    |10   |Jan 2021|
|ABC    |90   |Jul 2021|
|ABC    |40   |Jun 2021|
|ABC    |70   |Mar 2021|
|ABC    |20   |May 2021|
|ABC    |120  |Nov 2021|
|ABC    |50   |Oct 2021|
|ABC    |60   |Sep 2021|
+-------+-----+--------+
```